# Css layout, table or not

Tags: html, css, html-table

I need to implement a layout like that for a CSS:

```
picture: description
picture: description
   .
   .
   .
picture: description
```

I'm tempted of doing it something like:

```
<table>
       <tr>
            <td>picture</td>
            <td>description</td>
       </tr>
          .
          .
          .
</table>
```

But I've read that tables should be used only for strictly tabular data. My question is: is this the right case? If not, what would be a valid alternative?

Comment: In my opinion it is tabular data. There are alot of alternatives, but people saying that tables are only for something and divs are for other things probably never made "browser independent" sites.

Comment: The HTML5 `<figure>` and `<figcaption>` would be a good choice here. See [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/figure) for more info.

Comment: If you're not using HTML5 so can't use `<figure>`, I'd code it as a list - `<ul>` and `<li>` rather than a table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the new HTML5 elements for this as they are semantically rich.

```
figure and figcaption
```

This is how the mark up would look like in a website:

```
<figure>
    <img src="example.jpg" alt="example" />
    <figcaption>
      <p>This is the text I would use to describe the image</p>
    </figcaption>
</figure>
```

Here is the [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8W5eG/) I used floats for position and widths for the layout, which always can be changed by you.

Comment: Ok thanks. This has shown me valid tools I wasn't aware of. By the way, by your fiddle, it is not clear how one could center the <p> with respect to the image. Thank you though!